# SCNMaterial not changing color when setting 'diffuse.contents'

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a bunch of cubes (`SCNBox` for the `geometry` of an `SCNNode`).

The cubes each have a single `SCNMaterial` (a `UIColor`) assigned to their respective `materials` array.

Here's what that looks like:

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 3.0, height: 3.0, length: 3.0, chamferRadius: 0.2)
let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
let material = SCNMaterial()

material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

box.materials = [material]

(self.view as! SCNView).scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
```

When you tap on one of these cubes, I *try* to change their color to green by doing the following:

```
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
```

But this doesn't always work! Sometimes the cube turns green as desired, and sometimes it stays red.

I've tested some theories, and I've established the following:

1. The code that sets the cube's color to green *does*, indeed, run.
2. The material is, indeed, set to green (I inspected `material.diffuse.contents` via `print()`), and I can see that the color was set correctly.
3. The code that determines which cube was tapped works correctly. So, it's not a matter of hit testing or anything like that.
4. The problem happens on both Simulator and device.

For lighting, I'm simply using `scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true`. No additional lights involved.

**Question: Has anyone else experienced this problem? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a legitimate bug?**

**EDIT:**
Here's a bit more information about how I'm trying to set the color of the cubes when tapped:

```
@objc
func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])

    if hitResults.count > 0 {
        let result = hitResults[0]
        let material = result.node.geometry?.firstMaterial

        if let material = material {
            print("GREEN") //Prints "GREEN" every time, as expected -- but sometimes the cube turns green and sometimes it does not.
            material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT #2:**
I've managed to get this working, but I'm left with more questions than answers.

Instead of updating the cubes' color by setting `material.diffuse.contents`, I tried using `material.emission.contents`. For whatever reason, this works 100% of the time, as desired.

The downside is that the visual appearance of the cubes when setting `material.emission.contents` is a bit odd, and not necessarily what I'm looking for. It's green, yes -- but it's different somehow. But that's another matter.

Feel free to post an answer to this question if you can explain these behaviors.

Comment: @AndyJazz I'm on Xcode 13.2.1 and will update (thanks for the heads up). Seems unlikely to me, however, that `material.diffuse.contents` would behave so drastically different in my (pretty recent) Xcode version.

Comment: You could try to set the material color directly, without going trough a new material (if let material) - like so: result.node.geometry?.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample code in Xcode 13.3 on macOS 12.3.1, everything works fine (app and simulator).

Make sure you're using `UITapGestureRecognizer`, not `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
(self.view as! SCNView).addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```